# (Windows 10 Pro) Set task scheduler to gracefully shutdown when switching to battery

Tags: windows-10, battery, shutdown, scheduled-tasks, microsoft-surface-pro-3

Long story short, we have a requirement tossed on us to make a Surface 3 shut down upon commercial power loss. I have went through Microsoft support, and we tried several things to attempt to disable the battery and allow "hard" off which is what the spec requires.  This would not work.  Opening the surface is a self destruct suicide mission and a waste of time across 20 of them.  So I am attempting to execute a soft-off with " shutdown.exe /s /t 1 " My loss is at how to hook that command into Task scheduler.  I have found many batch file examples to check the current state but I would think task scheduler would be able to hook into Window's own Broadcast messages that it sends when battery state is switched.   Any help?

As suggested, here are ***basic requirements***:

~Needs to operate at a near baseline level, so when the computer is groddy/barely running because of memory leaks or other software freezing, it could potentially still run.

~Needs to be able to shut the PC down

**Reasoning behind**:

This is for a multimedia touch display which will have custom built x 20 software running fullscreen.  It is to be fully PoE.  We have engineered a wall mounting kit and the ability to put all devices(splitters/converters/adapters) behind it in a 4" square box.  We need the ability to conduct hard resets over the network if a soft reset fails.  The simplest solution would be no battery, disable PoE to port, then it shuts down.  This is not possible per microsoft.  The next step would be windows executing a shutdown if Power is lost (switching to battery)  as this would be our steps if a network command to reset fails. Network port binding up/crashing/ect..  Hence why Task scheduler was chosen as the route as being baked into windows, it has a better chance of running still if other things are broken.

Comment: Is using the task scheduler an absolute requirement, or would you be willing to accept alternative solutions that accomplish the same goal? How about suggestions that perform the shutdown in some way other than executing that specific command, but gives the same effect? Please [edit] your question to clarify what are requirements, and what are simply ideas about or illustrations for what you want to achieve.

Comment: I added in extra information as to what we need and why we need it.

Comment: Very good, thank you. I don't have an answer for you, but the information should help someone come up with a solution to your problem.